# invalid argument supplied on c# udp socket

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

I've been trying to make a simple udp chat application in c#. it was working an hour ago, but I don't exactly realize what happened to it or what exactly I've changed in it. when I try to listen for any incoming messages, I just get an exception saying "Invalid argument was supplied", pointing to the variable 'rcv'. Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                                  SocketType.Dgram, 
                                   ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),
                                                                   1234);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(send));
            thread1.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(receive));
            thread2.Start();
        }

        private void receive()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] rcv = new byte[2048];
                int size = sock.Receive(rcv); // this is where the exception is, pointing at rcv.
                char[] chars = new char[size];

                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                int length = d.GetChars(rcv, 0, size, chars, 0);
                System.String recv = new System.String(chars);

                textBox1.Text += recv.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void send()
        {
            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            sock.SendTo(msg, localEndPoint);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sock.Close();
        }
    }
```

I've honestly never seen this exception while working with sockets. I thought maybe the socket was open and in use so I tried closing it but with no success.
Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx):

> If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, you must either call `Connect` to establish a remote host connection, or `Accept` to accept an incoming connection prior to calling `Receive`. The `Receive` method will only read data that arrives from the remote host established in the `Connect` or `Accept` method. If you are using a connectionless protocol, you can also use the `ReceiveFrom` method. `ReceiveFrom` will allow you to receive data arriving from any host.

It appears you are not calling `Connect`, `Accept`, or `ReceiveFrom` in any case. Since a chat application follows (logically) a connection-oriented protocol, you should probably call `Connect` or `Accept` somewhere prior to `Receive`.